# How to close a question with the author’s consent?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I wanted to help close [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/45038/5864) where the author says in the comments area that the question can be closed because they didn’t really ask what they were looking for (asked about numerical stability while actually looking for numerical precision).

I'm tempted to close using “not constructive” but I fear I would look a bit rude if the moderators don’t read all the comments. What’d be the best option?

Answer (score 3):

You can always flag for moderator attention with a custom explanation. (i.e. the "other" option) Briefly detail what the situation is and why you flag. It should then be perfectly clear to the moderator what your intentions are and they can act (or reject, if they feel the need to) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I was focusing on “close” whereas “flag” was probably a better idea.